# How do I run shell command in swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm doing a macOS app, trying to run shell command in child process. I'll get an error `Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13` if I don't set launchPath to `/usr/bin/env`, why is it like this? How can I run shell command in other path?

```
class Helper {
    static func shell(launchPath path: String, arguments args: [String]) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = path
        task.arguments = args

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        task.waitUntilExit()

        return(output!)
    }
}

let res = Helper.shell(launchPath: "/Users/myUserName", arguments: ["ls"]) //error
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to access to a path like `/Users/myName/myWorkspace`, 
but you have first, to disable the app sandbox doing so:

[image]

If you want to run `ls` in a custom directory, you might try this example:

```
let res = Helper.shell(launchPath: "/bin/ls", arguments: ["/Users/myUserName/myworkspace"])
print("*** ls ***:\n\(res)")
```

in my case I have the following output:

```
*** ls ***:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: I'm not clear about the launchPath. Can I run command under other path like `/Users/myName/myWorkspace`

Comment: Sure. Check the edit, added some useful informations

Comment: what if I want to run some cli programme under specific path, for example `npm ls` under `/Users/myUserName/myworkspace`, then where should I put the path ?

Comment: I think the best is having a shell script where you can easily add all your commands, then with the `Process` you just need to launch the script.

Comment: Ok, can I put my sh file somewhere in my app in this case ?

Comment: Would running my own shell script be allowed in the sandbox? I tried to call launcthl, but the console says "operation not permitted" - when I disable the sandbox, it works fine (not really that suprising).

Answer (score 1):

the `launch()` function is deprecated, using `run()`

```swift
if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
  try? task.run()
} else {
  task.launch()
}
```

or using [swift-commands](https://github.com/QiuZhiFei/swift-commands)

```swift
import Commands

Commands.Bash.run("ls")
```