# How to launch a Command Line Tool from app in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, shell

How does one invoke a command line tool from an app? I'd like to package the app with the command line tool and be able to launch it when the app launches.

When I try to use

```
func openCommandLineTool() {
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/filepath/"))
}
```

It tells me the application does not have permission to launch the command line tool.

My goal is to have an app that only launches the command line tool. How can I build this command line tool into the app? Is it possible?

Comment: please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48376150/2450755 and up-vote if you find it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by going to the .entitlements file within Xcode and selecting 'NO' for both 'App Sandbox' and 'com.apple.security.files.user'.